# PHP SHA1 gives different result than expected

Tags: php, sha1

This really surprises me - this should be rather simple, but I can't figure out what the difference is.

I have this function to generate a salt:

```
private function _generateSalt($max = 128)
{
    $characterList = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!#¤%&/()~";
    $i = 0;
    $salt = "";
    do {
        $salt .= $characterList{mt_rand(0,strlen($characterList)-1)};
         $i++;
    } while ($i < $max);
    return $salt;
}
```

Pretty basic(?)

And trying to create a SHA1 hash from this, gives me a different result what I would expect:

```
$salt = $this->_generateSalt();
$password = $salt.$password;
echo sha1($password);
```

$password is a string generated by user input.
The echoed hashed string is wrong. And I don't know why.

`var_dump($password);` after prepending the salt gives me the expected string size - copy and paste the result to an online SHA1 service or hashing the string through MySQL CLI gives the correct result. It's like there's something invisible in the $password variable I wan't to hash. But how can I find out why this is happening? var_dump(), trim() and comparing results haven't gotten me anywhere?

Comment: Well dump the password and the salt before concatenating them together and paste the result (for one call, of course every time the salt is different and you should keep it along with the password somewhere). What is the sha1 string you receive for a given EXACT string and what do you expect to receive?

Comment: My best guess is that there is a character you are not seeing somewhere (eg: a space)

Comment: I ask the php version because if you downloaded the latest version of php (5.3.7), it was stupidly released without unit testing and contains a serious crypto bug which practically disables crypto functions - http://developers.slashdot.org/story/11/08/22/2332217/Serious-Crypto-Bug-Found-In-PHP-537

Comment: @Veseliq: I found out the problem actually comes from the salt. The string generated, echoed out and copy-pasted to a sha1 function gives another result than the echoed sha1 string from the script. But can anyone identify whats wrong with me salt generator, then?

Comment: Again, tell your salt. And understand that every time the salt is different. If you copy and paste the salt to online SHA1 hash generator and then run again the script - it will give new result due to the new salt. Also get rid of all the non alpha-numeric special characters - this one is even not ASCII as far as I can tell: ¤. So it might mess things up if you run sha1 under string encoded in different encodings.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same salt ?

Comment: @Repox This is an overly complicated way to generate a salt, but its also pretty weak. See my post below plz.

Comment: @Veseliq: You are right - the non alpha-numeric characters in the salt was the problem. Removing them solved the problem. Could you post an answer so I can close this question?

Comment: Using random number generator to generate a salt which is totally random and then prepended to a constant password and you wonder why it doesn't "work".. It works properly, only your logic is out of place here. Of course you'll get different results with different salts.

Comment: @N.B: You should take the time to read all the comments. There is nothing wrong with my logic in the code. Following Veseliq's suggestion solved my problem and the rest of my script and it's logic works exactly as I expected.

Comment: There is. You were using a random number to generate the salt. You had a logical bug opposed to syntax bug. Since the number is always random, hashing the pass with different salt every time produces the unexpected hash. It's a logical bug.

Comment: @N.B: The salt is supposed to be random. The problem was that the non alpha-numeric characters in the salt gave unexpected SHA1 results. The whole point of my script is to randomly prepend a salt to the usergenerated password and hashing it. Please, try to understand the real problem instead of making up a non-existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of all the non alpha-numeric special characters - this one is even not ASCII as far as I can tell: ¤. So it might mess things up if you run sha1 under string encoded in different encodings.

(This answer is copy pasted from the comments and added as an answer because of the asker's request as it seem to fix the problem)

Answer (score 0):

A better way to generate a salt would be:

```
// True for cryptographically strong, FALSE otherwise
$salt_strong = TRUE;

// The length
$salt_length = 32;

// Create the salt and load the results into a local var
$salt = bin2hex( openssl_random_pseudo_bytes( $salt_length , $salt_strong ) );
```

Comment: The question was "why doesn't this work", not "how can I do this better".

Comment: I don't consider making weak code work to be a benefit to anyone. He is using mt_rand() in the process of password hashing which a huge no no. It is common knowledge for any php developer worth his "salt" that the Mersenne Twister used by mt_rand() is weak and should not be used for anything that may need to withstand a cryptographic attack. So instead I provided him with a solution that was easier, requires less code, less prone to errors, is cryptographically safe and.....will work.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Additionally, this requires openssl to be installed, which can and will bring compatibility problems.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't this line:
`$salt .= $characterList{mt_rand(0,strlen($characterList)-1)};`

Look like this: `$salt .= $characterList[mt_rand(0,strlen($characterList)-1)];`

Comment: No, you can access individual characters in a string via {} and [].